# How to convert array inside an array

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me with this.

how do i convert this

```
var array_name = ["Name1", "Name2"];
var array_score = [8, 9];
```

into like this

```
var mydata = [ ["Name1", "Name2"],[8,9] ]
```

I want my array_name and array score be joined together like the mydata array.
Can anyone help me with this,? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
var array_name = ["Name1", "Name2"];
var array_score = [8, 9];

var mydata =[];

mydata.push(array_name,array_score);
console.log(mydata)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zbwt9wdL/)

Answer (score 6):

`var mydata = [array_name, array_score]`

Answer (score 0):

> Here is some examples :

```js
var array_name  = ["Name1", "Name2"];
var array_score = [8, 9];

/*Example 1 :*/
var mydata = [];
mydata = [array_name,array_score];
console.log(mydata);

/*Example 2 :*/
var mydata = [];
mydata[0] = array_name;
mydata[1] = array_score;
console.log(mydata);

/*Example 3 :*/
var mydata = [];
mydata.push(array_name);     /*OR mydata.push(arr1,arr2,....);*/
mydata.push(array_score);
console.log(mydata);
```